# Calling Amazon Polly using VBA in Excel only works with English

Tags: excel, amazon-web-services, french

I have an excel file that has data in English and French.   I have a macro that uses VBA code to call Amazon Polly and retrieves an output in the form of an mp3 file onto my local disk.  It works fine for English, but gives me this error for French.

"Call to AWS Polly failed:403 Forbidden {"message": The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method.  Consult the service documentation for details."}

I'm fairly sure the problem is not related to my sign in credentials as it works fine for English. Also, it works for the French words that have no special characters, like diacritics.  Does this have something to do with some encoding/decoding issue or is it on the Amazon side?

Comment: You need to ready more closely the [Amazon Polly API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/API_SynthesizeSpeech.html). My first question is are your encoding your text in UTF-8?

Comment: I have the French phrase in a cell in Excel.   I am passing that value into a Subroutine that uses AWS like so,  
    Dim httpResponse As Object
    Set httpResponse = aws.callWebService("application/json", requestParameters)

Comment: I have the French phrase in a cell in Excel.   I am passing that value into a Subroutine using ssml and AWS.  My question is how do I get this to work for French, or any language other than English.  There are no examples anywhere.   I suspect this has something to do with the encoding since VBA in excel uses UTF-8, but what is needed is Unicode to support other languages' character sets.  Am I right?  and if so, how do I do this ?

Comment: Show the code you use... when sending a French word which has to be UTF-8, are you specifying fr-FR ?

Comment: Dim httpResponse As Object
Set httpResponse = aws.callWebService("application/json", reqParam)
                                                                                            works when reqParam ={"OutputFormat": "mp3", "Text": "<speak>etudiants</speak>", "TextType": "ssml", "VoiceId": "Lea"}                                                                                                                                           But does not work with:     {"OutputFormat": "mp3", "Text": "<speak>étudiants</speak>", "TextType": "ssml", "VoiceId": "Lea"}

Comment: Some more info, the request does not work also when VoiceId = "Léa" instead of "Lea".  Simply put, Polly doesn't like any characters that are not English.

Comment: PeterT, I have read the full Amazon Polly API forwards and backwards and I still don't see what is wrong with my program.  Do you have any additional suggestions?   I have been stuck on this for a week now and I really need to get this to work or I will have to switch to Google or Microsoft's Text-Speech engines.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Code to call AWS Polly. If successful, returns a HTTP response object that contains the file.

```
Option Explicit

' Calls AWS Polly to prononuce sWord using sVoice and the AWS keys.
' Returns a MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP response
Function CallPolly(sWord As String, sVoiceID As String, sOutputFormat As String, sAccessKey As String, _
                   sSecretKey As String, Optional sRegion As String = "eu-central-1") As Object

    Set CallPolly = Nothing

    Dim sHost, sEndpoint, sContentType, sRequestParameters, sAMZDate, sDateStamp, _
        sStringtoSign, sCanonicalURI, sCanonicalQueryString, sCanonicalRequest, _
        sPayloadhash, sCredentialScope, sSignature, sSignedHeaders, _
        sCanonicalHeaders, sAuthorizationHeader As String

    Dim dtDateTime As Date

    Const sService As String = "polly"
    Const sMethod As String = "POST"
    Const sAPI As String = "/v1/speech"
    Const sAlgorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"


    ' Check access and secret keys
    If ((sAccessKey = "") Or (sSecretKey = "")) Then
        Debug.Print (vbLf & "No access key is available.")
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Build host and endpoint from what we know
    sHost = sService & "." & sRegion & ".amazonaws.com"
    sEndpoint = "https://" & sHost & sAPI

    ' POST requests use a content type header. For Polly,
    ' the content is JSON.
    sContentType = "application/x-amz-json-1.0"

    ' Request parameters for Polly, passed in a JSON block.
    ' Reference:
    ' https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/API_SynthesizeSpeech.html
    sRequestParameters = "{""OutputFormat"": """ & sOutputFormat & """, "
    sRequestParameters = sRequestParameters & """Text"": ""<speak>" & sWord & "</speak>"", "
    sRequestParameters = sRequestParameters & """TextType"": ""ssml"", "
    sRequestParameters = sRequestParameters & """VoiceId"": """ & sVoiceID & """}"

    Debug.Print (vbLf & "RequestParameters:" & vbLf & sRequestParameters)

    ' Create a date for headers and the credential string
    dtDateTime = getNowInUTC()
    sAMZDate = Format(dtDateTime, "yyyymmdd\Thhnnss\Z")
    sDateStamp = Format(dtDateTime, "yyyymmdd") ' Date w/o time, used in credential scope

    ' ************************************
    ' * TASK 1: CREATE A CANONICAL REQUEST
    ' ************************************
    '
    ' Reference:
    ' http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html

    ' Step 1: define the verb (GET, POST, etc.). Here: POST. Did that above by setting sMethod

    ' Step 2: Create canonical URI, i.e. the part of the URI from domain to query
    ' string.
    sCanonicalURI = sAPI

    ' Step 3: Create the canonical query string. In this example, request
    ' parameters are passed in the body of the request and the query string
    ' is blank.
    sCanonicalQueryString = ""

    ' Step 4: Create the canonical headers. Header names must be trimmed
    ' and lowercase, and sorted in code point order from low to high.
    ' Note that there is a trailing newline.
    sCanonicalHeaders = "content-type:" & sContentType & vbLf & _
                        "host:" & sHost & vbLf & _
                        "x-amz-date:" & sAMZDate & vbLf

    ' Step 5: Create the list of signed headers. This lists the headers
    ' in the canonical headers list, delimited with ";" and in alphabetical
    ' order.
    ' Note: The request can include any headers; canonical headers and
    ' signed hearders include those that you want to be included in the
    ' hash of the request. "Host" and "x-amz-date" are always required.
    ' For Polly, content-type and x-amz-target are also required.
    sSignedHeaders = "content-type;host;x-amz-date" ';x-amz-target"

    ' Step 6: Create payload hash. In this example, the payload (body of
    ' the request) contains the request parameters.
    Dim bytRequestParameters() As Byte
    bytRequestParameters = MyString2UTF8(sRequestParameters)
    Dim bytPayloadHash() As Byte
    bytPayloadHash = MySHA256(bytRequestParameters)
    sPayloadhash = MyByteArrayToHex(bytPayloadHash)

    ' Step 7: Combine elements to create canonical request
    sCanonicalRequest = sMethod & vbLf & _
                        sCanonicalURI & vbLf & _
                        sCanonicalQueryString & vbLf & _
                        sCanonicalHeaders & vbLf & _
                        sSignedHeaders & vbLf & _
                        sPayloadhash

    Debug.Print (vbLf & "Canonical Request:" & vbLf & sCanonicalRequest)

    ' ***********************************
    ' * TASK 2: CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN
    ' ***********************************

    ' Match the algorithm to the hashing algorithm you use.
    ' We are using SHA-256 as recommended, Did that above
    ' by setting the sAlgorithm constant

    Dim bytCanonicalRequest() As Byte
    bytCanonicalRequest = MyString2UTF8(sCanonicalRequest)
    sCredentialScope = sDateStamp & "/" & sRegion & "/" & sService & "/" & "aws4_request"
    sStringtoSign = sAlgorithm & vbLf & _
                    sAMZDate & vbLf & _
                    sCredentialScope & vbLf & _
                    MyByteArrayToHex(MySHA256(bytCanonicalRequest))

    Debug.Print (vbLf & "StringToSign:" & vbLf & sStringtoSign)

    ' *********************************
    ' * TASK 3: CALCULATE THE SIGNATURE
    ' *********************************

    ' Create the signing key
    Dim bytSigningKey() As Byte
    bytSigningKey = getSignatureKey(sSecretKey, sDateStamp, sRegion, sService)

    ' Sign sStringToSign using the signing key
    Dim bytStringToSign() As Byte
    bytStringToSign = MyString2UTF8(sStringtoSign)
    Dim bytSignature() As Byte
    bytSignature = MyHMACSHA256(bytStringToSign, bytSigningKey)
    sSignature = MyByteArrayToHex(bytSignature)

    ' ************************************************
    ' * TASK 4: ADD SIGNING INFORMATION TO THE REQUEST
    ' ************************************************

    ' Put the signature information in a header named Authorization.
    sAuthorizationHeader = sAlgorithm & " " & _
                           "Credential=" & sAccessKey & "/" & _
                           sCredentialScope & ", " & _
                           "SignedHeaders=" & sSignedHeaders & ", " & _
                           "Signature=" & sSignature

    Debug.Print (vbLf & "AuthorizationHeader:" & vbLf & sAuthorizationHeader)

    ' ******************
    ' * SEND THE REQUEST
    ' ******************

    Debug.Print (vbLf & "ATTENTION ALL UNITS!")
    Debug.Print (vbLf & "BEGIN REQUEST!")
    Debug.Print ("Request URL = " + sEndpoint)

    Dim oHTTP As Object
    Set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    oHTTP.Open "POST", sEndpoint, False

    ' For Polly, the request can include any headers, but MUST include "host", "content-type",
    ' "x-amz-date" and "authorization". Except for the authorization header,
    ' the headers must be included in the canonical headers and signed headers values, as
    ' noted earlier. Order here is not significant.

    oHTTP.setrequestheader "content-type", sContentType
    oHTTP.setrequestheader "host", sHost
    oHTTP.setrequestheader "x-amz-date", sAMZDate
    oHTTP.setrequestheader "authorization", sAuthorizationHeader

    ' Off you go, good luck
    oHTTP.Send sRequestParameters

    ' Return the HTTP response back to the calling program.
    Set CallPolly = oHTTP

End Function

' Key derivation function
Public Function getSignatureKey(ByVal sKey As String, ByVal sDateStamp As String, ByVal sRegionName As String, ByVal sServiceName As String) As Byte()

    Dim bytSecretKey() As Byte
    bytSecretKey = MyString2UTF8("AWS4" & sKey)

    Dim bytDateKey() As Byte
    bytDateKey = MyHMACSHA256(MyString2UTF8(sDateStamp), bytSecretKey)

    Dim bytRegionKey() As Byte
    bytRegionKey = MyHMACSHA256(MyString2UTF8(sRegionName), bytDateKey)

    Dim bytServiceKey() As Byte
    bytServiceKey = MyHMACSHA256(MyString2UTF8(sServiceName), bytRegionKey)

    Dim bytSigningKey() As Byte
    bytSigningKey = MyHMACSHA256(MyString2UTF8("aws4_request"), bytServiceKey)

    getSignatureKey = bytSigningKey

End Function

' get UTC date & time
Private Function getNowInUTC() As Date

    Dim dtUTCNow As Date
    Dim oDateTime As Object

    Set oDateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")

    oDateTime.SetVarDate Now
    getNowInUTC = oDateTime.GetVarDate(False)

    Set oDateTime = Nothing

End Function

Option Explicit

' WinApi function mapping UTF-16 (wide character) string to another format
Private Declare Function WideCharToMultiByte Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal CodePage As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lpWideCharStr As Long, _
    ByVal cchWideChar As Long, _
    ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long, _
    ByVal cbMultiByte As Long, _
    ByVal lpDefaultChar As Long, _
    ByVal lpUsedDefaultChar As Long) As Long

' Maps a character string to a UTF-16 (wide character) string
Private Declare Function MultiByteToWideChar Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal CodePage As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long, _
    ByVal cchMultiByte As Long, _
    ByVal lpWideCharStr As Long, _
    ByVal cchWideChar As Long _
    ) As Long

Private Declare Function CryptStringToBinary Lib "Crypt32" _
    Alias "CryptStringToBinaryW" ( _
    ByVal pszString As Long, _
    ByVal cchString As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal pbBinary As Long, _
    ByRef pcbBinary As Long, _
    ByRef pdwSkip As Long, _
    ByRef pdwFlags As Long) As Long

' CodePage constant for UTF-8
Private Const CP_UTF8 = 65001

' Return length of a byte array
Private Function BytesLength(bytBytes() As Byte) As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    BytesLength = UBound(bytBytes) - LBound(bytBytes) + 1

End Function

' Convert a String to an UTF-8-encoded array of bytes
Public Function MyString2UTF8(ByVal strInput) As Byte()

    Dim lngBytes As Long
    Dim bytBuffer() As Byte

    If (strInput = "") Then Exit Function

    ' Get length of strInput in bytes including terminating null
    lngBytes = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0&, ByVal StrPtr(strInput), -1, 0&, 0&, 0&, 0&)

    ' Dim bytBuffer to disregard the terminating null
    ReDim bytBuffer(lngBytes - 2)
    lngBytes = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0&, ByVal StrPtr(strInput), -1, ByVal VarPtr(bytBuffer(0)), lngBytes - 1, 0&, 0&)

    MyString2UTF8 = bytBuffer

End Function

' Convert an array of bytes to a string containg the bytes' hex values
Function MyByteArrayToHex(ByRef bytBytes() As Byte) As String

   Dim lngPosInString As Long, lngPosInBytes As Long
   Dim sBuffer As String
   MyByteArrayToHex = ""

   If IsEmpty(bytBytes) Then Exit Function

   sBuffer = Space$(2 * (UBound(bytBytes) - LBound(bytBytes)) + 2)
   lngPosInString = 1
   For lngPosInBytes = LBound(bytBytes) To UBound(bytBytes)
      Mid$(sBuffer, lngPosInString, 2) = LCase(Right$("00" & Hex$(bytBytes(lngPosInBytes)), 2))
      lngPosInString = lngPosInString + 2
   Next

   MyByteArrayToHex = sBuffer

End Function

' hash a message, provided as byte array, using SHA256
Public Function MySHA256(ByRef bytMessage() As Byte) As Byte()

    Dim bytBuffer() As Byte
    Dim oSHA256 As Object
    Set oSHA256 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed")

    bytBuffer = oSHA256.ComputeHash_2(bytMessage)

    MySHA256 = bytBuffer

    Set oSHA256 = Nothing

End Function

' compute the HMAC of a message, provided as byte array, with a secret key using SHA256
Public Function MyHMACSHA256(ByRef bytMessage() As Byte, ByRef bytSecretKey() As Byte) As Byte()

    Dim oEncoder As Object, oHMACSHA256 As Object

    Set oEncoder = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set oHMACSHA256 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256")

    oHMACSHA256.Key = bytSecretKey

    Dim bytBuffer() As Byte
    bytBuffer = oHMACSHA256.ComputeHash_2(bytMessage)
    MyHMACSHA256 = bytBuffer

    Set oEncoder = Nothing
    Set oHMACSHA256 = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Thank for uploading the code, I wish to repurpose it (not using it for Polly but for Amazon's SP-API), alas MS Access VBA barfs....at this point
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuH64.jpg

Any ideas? (I suspect it might have something to do with 32 vs 64 MS Access...I'm on 32 bit)